# How to auto indent jsx in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

VSCode seems doesn't auto indent HTML elements in jsx?

[image]

Is there any way to fix it.

---

**Update**:

In **Atom**:

When I input `<div>`, atom will show:
[image]

After I press the `return` key, the result is(pay attention to the location of the cursor):
[image]

While in **VSCode**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 57):

Try changing the language mode to JavaScript React.

1. Open the commands palette.
2. Type `change language mode`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type `javascript react`
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Once that's done, you'll see the JavaScript React mode in the bottom left corner.

[image: Confirmation of JavaScript React Mode]

Once you're in that mode, try again to format the document.

Comment: @zhuscat What command are you issuing to format the code? It Works on My Machine (TM).

Comment: @zhuscat Aha. I thought you were talking about the "Format Document" command. Your question update clarifies what you're needing.

Comment: I just want that when I press the `return` key, there is one more indent compared to the `<div>` in the example of my question.

Comment: And I'm wondering if there is any way to automatically add HTML close tag in `jsx`

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for are two things @zhuscat. One of them is auto-indent. The other is tag completion. For the latter, have you looked into emmet?

Comment: I installed a plugin called `auto close tag` to solve the "tag completion" problem. However, the `press return key` problem(when I press the return key, I hope there is one more indent compared to the <div> in the example of my question) is still there.

Comment: For closing the tag, you can type for example `div` without brackets, and press tab. I'm having the same issues with auto-indenting though. Actually, it goes to the next line tabbed in, but my problem is that the closing tag doesn't tab back out.

Comment: This doesn't work when the closing bracket is on a new line: https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohc0Y4D2kzfD2IVNu/html5

Answer (score 55):

Change the language to `Javascript React` (see other answers for instructions) then use the following command:

```
alt + shift + f
```

Comment: This works on Windows, but not on my Ubuntu, where `alt+shift+f` opens File menu

Comment: Does this shortcut uses eslint config for formatting or the default?

Comment: I think it's using the builtin emmet

Comment: Is there any way so that it formats the code automatically when I save the file? Pressing this key combination is an extra step.

Answer (score 3):

use the extension "Prettier - Code formatter", by Esben Petersen. it will auto format on save, assuming your file is a jsx file.

Comment: You need to actually activate that setting as well.

Comment: The best answer.

Comment: but when we type we to format experice like in .html file

Answer (score 1):

**1.
Add user settings to**

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
},
```

**2. Install plugin**

`Auto Install Tag`

And Reload. It will fix your issue.

BTW, I think there's a bug now. Without component props auto indent work well, but with props, it won't work now.

`<Component>Enter`

===>

```
<Component>
    :
</Component>
```

But

`<Component someProps={10}}Enter`

===>

```
<Component someProps={10}>
:</Component>
```

Anyone who can fix this please help me :) I am using on mac