# Visual Studio Code auto indent in JSX

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I have this code in .jsx file:

[image: Code sample]

Now if I type, for example, `BrowserRouter` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> I got this state which is still ok:

[image]

But now when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I have this state:

[image]

How do I make it work like in `.html` files that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> adds two new lines and makes auto indentation? Like that:

[image]

I have VS Code v1.20.1 and my preferences which could be related to this issue are as follows:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

I've searched through Github issues of VS Code and seems like it was fixed about half a year ago and should work now, but for some reason it's not. Also I've run VS Code with `--disable-extensions` flag for this so it's not an extension problem.

I've also found that it seems not to work **for top-level tag only**. For anything inside it the indentation works like in `.html` files. Strange.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, long ago - but did you find any solution? I've met the completely same issue now - with the most recent VSC version.. Very irritating(

Comment: @AlexGreen No, I haven't found a solution. I don't write jsx that often now because of my current work on backend, so I haven't been digging too deep to resolve the issue.

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40520170/3347508

Comment: @5tormTrooper I had passed by that answer too before I asked this question, but I had "JavaScript React" mode already on.

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this, 2022. Any luck? It's annoying that it is not indent new lines inside of html/component tags...