# VS Code Settings messing op JSX formatting

Tags: jsx, visual-studio-code

My VS Code editor is having issues with JSX. One time it will format the code below like this and generate errors. If I restart VS Code, it will correct the format issues for a little while until I work on and save a different js file. Once I come back to App.js, the wierd formatting shows up again. Any ideas what I can change in my settings?

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( <
            div className = "App" >
            <
            Header branding = "Contact Info" / >
            <
            h1 > The Contact Component < /h1> <Contact / >

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution here: [How to auto indent jsx in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498622/how-to-auto-indent-jsx-in-vscode)

1) Open the commands palette.
2) Type change language mode
3) Press Enter
3) Type javascript react
5) Press Enter

Comment: it works but i need to do it for each file. how to change it for whole project for a given file extension?